Use Dart Package only for iOS devices
I want to use flutter_ads_package: ^1.2.9 but I am getting some runtime errors for Android devices.
Is there any way that you can install a package only for one platform...in that case iOS in the pubspec.yaml file?

This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60336921/how-to-import-dart-file-or-package-dependent-on-flutter-platform as does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710226/how-to-import-platform-specific-dependency-in-flutter-dart-combine-web-with-an
